# does closing the browser stop a running server process (System backup i.e.)?

Tags: backend, backup

Let's say I started a backup in the Magento backend `[->System ->tools ->backups]` before going home in the evening.

Can I shut down my computer while the backup (or whatever process I started) is still running or would this kill the process running on the server side?

I assume, whatever the answer may be (my guess *"yes, you can shut down your computer or browser. The server will continue whatever process has been started through the backend GUI"*), the same is true for refreshing/closing the browser's tab. Am I assuming right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right!

The process will continue to run on server side no matter the browser closing, pc shutdown!